STM32F411 SPI read always returns 0xFF
I am trying my best to read data from an SD card using SPI. It works using HAL, but it's very slow, so I am trying to code my own SPI driver. I am stuck on trasnmitting data.
The GPIO implementation is not faulty, so it must be the SPI implementation. I have looked at dozens of bare metal STM32 SPI implementations, and could not find any difference between mine and theirs.
void fhSpiInit(u32 pScaler)
{
    fhGpioInitSystemA();

    fhGpioPinSetupA(FH_GPIO_PIN_07, FH_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE, FH_GPIO_OTYPE_PUSH_PULL, FH_GPIO_SPEED_HIGH, FH_GPIO_PULL_NONE);
    fhGpioPinSetupA(FH_GPIO_PIN_06, FH_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE, FH_GPIO_OTYPE_PUSH_PULL, FH_GPIO_SPEED_HIGH, FH_GPIO_PULL_NONE);
    fhGpioPinSetupA(FH_GPIO_PIN_05, FH_GPIO_MODE_ALTERNATE, FH_GPIO_OTYPE_PUSH_PULL, FH_GPIO_SPEED_HIGH, FH_GPIO_PULL_NONE);
    fhGpioPinSetupA(FH_GPIO_PIN_03, FH_GPIO_MODE_OUTPUT, FH_GPIO_OTYPE_PUSH_PULL, FH_GPIO_SPEED_HIGH, FH_GPIO_PULL_NONE);

    fhGpioAlternateFunctionA(FH_GPIO_PIN_07, 5);
    fhGpioAlternateFunctionA(FH_GPIO_PIN_06, 5);
    fhGpioAlternateFunctionA(FH_GPIO_PIN_05, 5);

    RCC->APB2RSTR &= ~RCC_APB2RSTR_SPI1;
    RCC->APB2ENR |= RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;

    SPI1->CR1 = 0;
    SPI1->CR2 = 0;

    SPI1->CR1 |= pScaler;
    SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_MSTR;
    SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSM;
    SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SSI;
    SPI1->CR1 |= SPI_CR1_SPE;

    fhSpiCsHigh();
}

void fhSpiDeinit()
{
    SPI1->CR1 &= ~SPI_CR1_SPE;
    RCC->APB2ENR &= ~RCC_APB2ENR_SPI1EN;
    RCC->APB2RSTR |= RCC_APB2RSTR_SPI1RST;
}

void fhSpiReInit(u32 pScaler)
{
    fhSpiDeinit();
    fhSpiInit(pScaler);
}

u8 fhSpiTransferByte(u8 pToWrite)
{
    SPI1->DR = pToWrite;

    halt(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_TXE));
    halt(!(SPI1->SR & SPI_SR_RXNE));
    u8 ret = SPI1->DR;

    printf("\tSPI1: %02x <=> %02x\n", pToWrite, ret);

    return ret;
}

void fhSpiCsLow()
{
    fhGpioPinWriteA(FH_GPIO_PIN_03, 0);
}

void fhSpiCsHigh()
{
    fhGpioPinWriteA(FH_GPIO_PIN_03, 1);
}

Maybe my wiring is the problem. I have checked the voltages: going into the STM microcontroller is 5.06V, and going into the SD card from the STM board is 3.44V (a little high, but should be OK).
The SD card driver is not mine, I used ulibSD to minimize errors.
My implementation of ulibSD SPI functions:
/**
    \brief Initialize SPI hardware
 */
void SPI_Init(void)
{
    fhSpiReInit(SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_256);
}

/**
    \brief Read/Write a single byte.
    \param d Byte to send.
    \return Byte that arrived.
 */
BYTE SPI_RW(BYTE d)
{
    return fhSpiTransferByte(d);
}

/**
    \brief Flush of SPI buffer.
 */
void SPI_Release(void)
{
    return;
}

/**
    \brief Selecting function in SPI terms, associated with SPI module.
 */
void SPI_CS_Low(void)
{
    fhSpiCsLow();
}

/**
    \brief Deselecting function in SPI terms, associated with SPI module.
 */
void SPI_CS_High(void)
{
    fhSpiCsHigh();
}

/**
    \brief Setting frequency of SPI's clock to maximun possible.
 */
void SPI_Freq_High(void)
{
    fhSpiReInit(SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_2);
}

/**
    \brief Setting frequency of SPI's clock equal or lower than 400kHz.
 */
void SPI_Freq_Low(void)
{
    fhSpiReInit(SPI_BAUDRATEPRESCALER_256);
}

uint32_t gSpiTimerEnd = 0;

/**
    \brief Start a non-blocking timer.
    \param ms Milliseconds.
 */
void SPI_Timer_On(WORD ms)
{
    gSpiTimerEnd = gSysTick + ms;
}

/**
    \brief Check the status of non-blocking timer.
    \return Status, TRUE if timeout is not reach yet.
 */
BOOL SPI_Timer_Status(void)
{
    if (gSpiTimerEnd == -1)
    {
        return false;
    }

    if (gSysTick >= gSpiTimerEnd)
    {
        SPI_Timer_Off();
        return false;
    }

    return true;
}

/**
    \brief Stop of non-blocking timer. Mandatory.
 */
void SPI_Timer_Off(void)
{
    gSpiTimerEnd = -1;
}





USB_VCC -> STM_5V
USB_GND -> STM_GND
SD_GND -> STM_GND
SD_VDD -> STM_3V3
SD_MOSI -> STM_MOSI1
SD_MISO -> STM_MISO1
SD_CLK -> STM_CLK1
SD_CS -> STM_A3
Edit:
Forgot to paste my output log, sorry!
Output:
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: 40 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 95 <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: 40 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 95 <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: 40 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 95 <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: 40 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 95 <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: 40 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 95 <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: 40 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 00 <=> ff
        SPI1: 95 <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
        SPI1: ff <=> ff
SD_Init: 1

As you can see, the driver consistently reads 0xFF no matter what.

There is no real reason the HAL implementation should be especially slow since the data rate over SPI is significantly lower than the instruction execution rate (assuming you have programmed the PLL appropriately).  How slow is "very slow"?  SD card performance over SPI is very variable, and often nowhere near what you'd expect over SDIO or from the card spec. A read performance of 128kb/s is typical I'd say.  There are plenty of reasons not to use the HAL, but in this case performance is not one of them.  You will get best performance using DMA which your driver does not use.

When I was using the HAL SPI driver, the maximum transfer rate I would get is 30KB/s. That is apsurd, since I was running the APB2 clock at 48MHz. The lowest SPI prescaler is /2, which gives me a 24MHz SPI clock pulse. That is just below the SD SPI maximum (25MHz). I looked into the HAL SPI implementation, it has millions of checks and general bloatware, so no wonder it is running at such low speeds. Yes, you are correct, I did not use DMA, my plan is to first get SPI SD working without DMA and then add it afterwards.

While the rate you observe is indeed slow, I doubt it is explained by the number of instructions processed.  SPI is slow compared to the CPU instruction rate, and SD is slow compared to SPI with a great deal of busy-waiting.  If the board layout is poor, 24MHz could be too fast for good signal integrity, and halving it will make little difference to actual throughput.  If using DMA (which I believe the HAL driver supports), the instruction count is even less relevant. Most of the time will be DMA transfers of 512 byte sectors (or larger) with no software overhead at all.

Your time would be better spent analysing the real reason for poor performance, or verifying your assumptions.  Ideally you would scope the SPI to see what is actually going on, and profile the code in your debugger.

I would say that that breadboard wiring is unlikely to sustain 24MHz with good signal integrity.  Over SPI you would be lucky to see 1MB/S regardless of SPI clock rate, so an SCLK of 8MHz would be adequate and likely more reliable given the breadboard.

Note also that SD over SPI involves a lot of busy-polling, where the busy/not ready response is FF.  The faster you poll, the more busy responses you will get.  Also I have seen rates as low as 30kb/s that were purely down to the card.  Try a few different cards before you conclude it is a software issue.

The speed you got is most likely due to the minimum of 400kHz clock used for SD card (that's by the specification), probably it can be fixed by calling something in HAL (I'm not familiar with that at all) or performing some special steps. In any case it's good to have an oscilloscope connected to check. The 0xFF  issue is most likely due to wrong assumptions made about SD in SPI mode, note that SD abuses SPI protocol specifications during initialization, i.e. how CS pin should be driven.

Looking at the ulibSD porting layer you provided, I would suggest that your problem is BYTE SPI_RW(BYTE d).  If there is no API for a block-write you cannot benefit from DMA operations for sector read/write.  It will be very slow, regardless of the HAL,  I have never come across ulibSD before and it appears to be a low level sector read/write library and not an actual file system.  I would not recommend using SD cards in that way.  ELM FatFS is a full FAT filesystem, if PC compatibility is not required LittleFS is a robust power-fail safe filesystem.

Also what @0andriy said.  SD cards must be initialised at a low clock rate before switching to the high speed.  The ulibSD porting layer does not appear to have any means to control the clock speed, so presumably uses the lowest common denominator.   This is clearly and XY problem.  Your problem is that your transfer rate is low.  You should ask about that, rather then inventing an unlikely solution and asking how to implement it.  You may get it working and the transfer rate will likely be no higher.  So the answer to your question is not a solution to your problem.

Note that the ELM FatFs I mentioned is included at part of STM32Cube.
